# Why did the Print Statement in T-SQL solve my reporting issue?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a complex report running in T-SQL, which in query analyzer was running fine but whenever I ran it off the web it was getting timed out. So there I am trying to figure out what is going on and start debugging with print statements before and after each call. The problem is solved! Now the website is loading the report faster than it has ever loaded it and all I did was add print '1', print'2', and so on around each select nothing else. I haven't changed a line of code otherwise. I take those print statements out the code blows up again. Because of the print statements I know why I was getting the error. There was a NULL value in one of my aggregates. I still haven't fixed the data problem. I am confused as to why this has solved my problem, any thoughts?

Comment: You changed something and didn't realize it.

Comment: Possibly parameter sniffing. When you added the `print` statements you changed the text of the query meaning that it didn't match the existing plan in the cache and you got compiled a new one. If this is still reproducible check the execution plans for both versions.

Comment: Database Administrators SE would probably be a bit more qualified to answer this question.  (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If I changed something and didn't realize it then why can I reproduce it by removing the print statements? I guess the code fairy code be undoing that thing that I did that I don't know about just to confuse me.

Comment: Execution plans look the same. I still don't know why the problem was corrected on the web maybe because it returned something with the print statement and reset the timeout period. I am still getting the error in the data from the NULL reference, and I still get the web timeout if I pull out the print statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a long running query the chances are that you are reaching a timeout period as Varuuknahl has said.

Adding print statements would reset the timeout and your query would be given more time to return the main result set.

I suggest you either simplfy the query if possible, there are many people on this site who could help you with that or you could increase the timeout period in your web application which is calling this procedure/report to run.

If you want someone to fix the aggregated NULL problem you have, let us see the query and we can give some advice.

Comment: "Adding print statements would reset the timeout". Sounds unlikely to me. Wouldn't the command timeout be from when the query was first submitted.